# MySQL data types - will storing DATE type and TIME type separately saves me 2bytes per each record compering to DATETIME entry?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I was just wondering how should I store date and time in a database ? Since storing them together in one DATETIME column takes 8 bytes per record and storing the separate in two columns DATE and TIME will take 3 bytes each - that is 6 bytes in total per record. I know it's not much in terms of small to medium database but it also doesn't harm if someone wants to be politically correct. Is that even correct ? :) Or is there anything else to consider before spliting datetime into two columns ?

[image: Storage Requirements for Date and Time Types]

Again, when I look at the table above I would probably go for TIMESTAMP because i only takes 4 bytes, but knowing that the TIMESTAMP data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC I am not quite sure. Is that a good idea for long term ? I am not that old so I will still be there in 2038 and it just makes me wonder what will happen in '2038-01-19 03:14:0**8**' ... Will I have to create  DATE and TIME data types columns anyway? :)

Comment: It might save you a little room, but I would estimate it will cost you much more in time wrestling with the two fields than the 2MB per million records of storage is worth. (Example: just think out the conditions required for finding records between "yesterday at noon" and "today at noon"; and keep in mind using a function on the field values will eliminate the benefits of any indexes you might have on those fields AND slow it down by performing the operations on those fields for every row in the table.)

Comment: You are prabobly right about that. I would have to make some more sophisticated query to compare dates. What about TIMESTAMP ? Is it woth considering as alternative to DATETIME ? (at least untill 2038 :))

Comment: TIMESTAMP really depends on your use; it's obviously not going to be very reliable for birth/construction/founding/etc dates unless you limit the people/buidlings/organizations/etc represented to only those under the age of 46. I believe there are some slight behavioral differences between the types when it comes to timezones, and in valid default values (depends on MySQL version). I think worrying about the size of your date fields is still one of the last things you should consider when your best case savings is 4MB per million fields (unless your application is freakishly date-time heavy).

Comment: **don't do it** for space saving, consider the first comment v.carefully. Uueerdo's points a very valid. You will end-up adding date to time on innumerable occasions. You would need very specific functional requirements to benefit from splitting that data imho.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the table. I think thats for MySQL. This table is updated now for after 5.6.4 versions:
[Date/Time and Date time storage comparisons for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html). Where now is more convenient to save it as **datetime**.

Date = 3bytes
Time = 3bytes
Timestamp=5 bytes

Here you can look at a table for PostgresSQL: [Date/Time and Date time storage comparisons for Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-datetime.html)
Where you save more bytes saving it as `timestamp`.

Date = 4bytes
Time = 8bytes
Timestamp=8 bytes

On this link you can find the SQL Server comparison as well: [Date/Time and Datetime comparisons for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes) Where it is almost the same.

Date = 4bytes
Time = 3 to 5bytes
Timestamp=8bytes

I would answer yes to your question. My two cents on implementing it is that it depends on how you would query data.